# Invalid object name 'schema.table'

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sqlcmd

Here is some SQL I am trying to run via sqlcmd

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table')
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE schema.Table
        SET    description = @latestDescription
        WHERE  id = 'id' AND latest=1 AND description = @previousDescription


------------------------ Start of script log foot -------------------------------
        INSERT INTO dbo.ScriptLog ([name], [executionTime], [userName], [script])
        SELECT @scriptName, 
               GETDATE(), 
               SYSTEM_USER, 
               [text] 
        FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
        WHERE session_id = @@SPID

        INSERT INTO schema2.OneTimeExecutionLog([group], [artifact], [key], [timestamp], [description]) VALUES 
        ('test-group', 'test-artifact', @scriptName, GETDATE(), 'Update the description ');

        PRINT N'Successfully Update the description ';
        
     COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I am getting the following error:

> 10:17:42  Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server TOM, Line 717
> 10:17:42  Invalid object name 'schema.Table'.

But I managed to execute this query successfully using SSMS. My question is how do I get this to work using sqlcmd?

Comment: Odd table name, but both `table` and `schema` are reserved words (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words), and need to be delimited. Try `[schema].[Table]`.

Comment: those are not the actual names in my query. Just changed my table name and schema name for this post @jarlh

Comment: You are missing `BEGIN END` for the `IF`

Comment: I wonder if the OP comes from a python background, @Charlieface .

Comment: Don't use the catalog views if you care about the schema. It is not always going to be correct. Check the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Agreed yiou should use `sys.tables` and `sys.schemas` instead